# commenting out a printk statement causes crash in a linux device driver test

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, arm64

I'm seeing a weird case in a simple linux driver test(arm64).
The user program calls ioctl of a device driver and passes array 'arg' of uint64_t as argument. By the way, arg[2] contains a pointer to a variable in the app. Below is the code snippet.

```c
    case SetRunParameters:
        copy_from_user(args, (void __user *)arg, 8*3);
        offs = args[2] % PAGE_SIZE;
        down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
        res = get_user_pages( (unsigned long)args[2], 1, 1, &pages, NULL);
        if (res) {
            kv_page_addr = kmap(pages);
            kv_addr = ((unsigned long long int)(kv_page_addr)+offs);
            args[2] = page_to_phys(pages) + offset; // args[2] changed to physical
        }
        else {
            printk("get_user_pages failed!\n");
        }
        up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
        *(vaddr + REG_IOCTL_ARG/4) = virt_to_phys(args);  // from axpu_regs.h
        printk("ldd:writing %x at %px\n",cmdx,vaddr + REG_IOCTL_CMD/4); // <== line 248. not ok w/o this printk line why?..
        *(vaddr + REG_IOCTL_CMD/4) = cmdx;  // this command is different from ioctl cmd!
        put_page(pages); //page_cache_release(page);
        break;
    case ...
```

I have marked line 248 in above code. If I comment out the printk there, a trap occurs and the virtual machine collapses(I'm doing this on a qemu virtual machine). The `cmdx` is a integer value set according to the ioctl command from the app, and `vaddr` is the virtual address of the device (obtained from ioremap).  If I keep the printk, it works as I expect. What case can make this happen? (cache or tlb?)

Comment: Can you publish as well what the crash reports? If it reports something

Comment: because the virtual machine itself crashed, I couldn't see the report from the kernel on the VM. I see only this : ./runit20a: line 10: 16669 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -machine ab21q,gic-version=max,iommu=smmuv3 -m 1G -cpu max -smp 4 -netdev user,id=vnet,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:0-:22 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vnet -drive file=ab21q-ubuntu-20.04-image.img,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0,bootindex=0 -drive file=ubuntu-20.04-mini.iso,if=none,id=drive1,cache=writeback

Comment: -device virtio-blk,drive=drive1,bootindex=1 -drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash.  But this is from qemu crash.

Comment: Sometimes without the printk statement, it doesn't crash, but the value from the user land is not changed (the device is supposed to change the value). When it's ok(with the printk), the value has been changed by the device(qemu model).

Comment: I guess the `printk` call is acting as a barrier. You should be using `writel` to write the registers.

Comment: @IanAbbott Ah, thank you so much. You are correct. I didn't know writel has the barrier function. (and thought the ioremap takes care of the ordering problem too, through page table setup.  looks like it doesn't.). Can you put your answer with just a little explanation so that I can select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing memory-mapped registers by simple C constructs such as `*(vaddr + REG_IOCTL_ARG/4)` is a bad idea. You might get away with it on some platforms if the access is `volatile`-qualified, but it won't work reliably or at all on some platforms. The proper way to access memory-mapped registers is via the functions declared by `#include <asm/io.h>` or `#include <linux/io.h>`. These will take care of any arch-specific requirements to ensure that writes are properly ordered as far as the CPU is concerned<sup>1</sup>.

The functions for memory-mapped register access are described in the Linux kernel documentation under [Bus-Independent Device Accesses](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/device-io.html).

This code:

```
        *(vaddr + REG_IOCTL_ARG/4) = virt_to_phys(args);
        *(vaddr + REG_IOCTL_CMD/4) = cmdx;
```

can be rewritten as:

```
        writel(virt_to_phys(args), vaddr + REG_IOCTL_ARG/4);
        writel(cmdx, vaddr + REG_IOCTL_CMD/4);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Write-ordering for specific bus types such as PCI may need extra code to read a register inbetween writes to different registers if the ordering of the register writes is important. That is because writes are "posted" asynchronously to the PCI bus, and the PCI device may process writes to different registers out of order. An intermediate register read will not be handled by the device until all preceding writes have been handled, so it can be used to enforce ordering of posted writes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation. Changing it to writel made it work with or without the printk.